# How do I skip searching through a selected listbox item in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have created the code to search through each string within a listbox to get a substring up until the first space (this is the ID) and check whether the typed ID is in use.
I want to edit this code to skip checking the selected item within the listbox.

```
        For Each lstitem As String In Form1.lst_input.Items
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        For Each ch As Char In lstitem
            If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                Exit For
            Else : num += 1
            End If
        Next ch

        If lstitem.Substring(0, Val(num)) = txt_id.Text Then
            MsgBox("ID is currently in use", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ID in use")
            txt_id.Text = ""
            txt_id.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

I have tried:

```
        For Each lstitem As String In Form1.lst_input.Items(Not Form1.lst_input.SelectedItem)
```

and

```
            If lstitem Is Form1.lst_input.SelectedItem Then
```

but neither work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you use a typed datasource you would not have to parse anything. `ValueMember` would give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

I finially figured it out. I used the following code:

```
        For Each lstitem As String In Form1.lst_input.Items
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        If Not lstitem = Form1.lst_input.Items(Form1.lst_input.SelectedIndex) Then
            For Each ch As Char In lstitem
                If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                    Exit For
                Else : num += 1
                End If
            Next ch
        End If
        If lstitem.Substring(0, Val(num)) = txt_id.Text Then
            MsgBox("ID is currently in use", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ID in use")
            txt_id.Text = ""
            txt_id.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```